# What is the format for the minTime URI parameter in the VSTS REST API, Builds - List?

Tags: azure-devops

Given a VSTS REST API call like this:

```
https://*account*/*project*/_apis/build/builds?definitions=2&minTime=????queryOrder=startTimeDescending&api-version=4.1
```

What is the correct datetime format for the minTime value? Everything I have tried either returns all builds, or none, and is not filtering by date. For example, I have tried "31/08/2018", "2018-08-31T12:01:31.450Z", "08/31/2018". The format is not documented anywhere that I can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format for `minTime` should be `YYYY-MM-DD`.

So the request URL looks like:

```
https://marinaliu.visualstudio.com/Git2/_apis/build/builds?definitions=41&queryOrder=queueTimeDescending&minTime=2018-09-01&api-version=4.1
```

**Note:** when you specify `minTime` in the request url, it's not working to specify `queryOrder` with `startTimeDescending`. Instead, you can remove `&queryOrder=startTimeDescending` from url, or you can replace with `queueTimeDescending`.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried YYYY-MM-DD but it did not work because I was also using startTimeDescending.

Comment: @Polyfun yeah, that's the problem. Since your problem has been solved, could you mark the answer?

Answer (score 0):

`&minTime=2022-04-18T00:00:00&maxTime=2022-04-19T23:59:00`

This also worked for me with time component in addition to date component.